# Why shouldn't I nest h4 element inside h3?

Tags: html, visual-studio, warnings, standards

Why shouldn't I nest h4 element inside h3 ?
Why it is important to follow [w3c-recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) ?
[image: warning image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why shouldn't I nest h4 element inside h3 ?

Think about a printed document:

```css
h2, h3, h4 {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 + p, h3 + p, h4 + p {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>4. I am the main heading of a section</h2>
<p>I am an introduction to the section and an overview of the main points that will be covered.</p>

<h3>5.3 I am a sub-section heading</h3>
<p>I am a sub-section. I cover points in detail.</p>

<h4>6.1.2 I am a heading of a sub-section within the sub-section</h4>
<p>I am a sub-section within a sub-section. I provide quite deep detail on a particular aspect of the topic under discussion.</p>
```

Now think about nesting a sub-sub-heading like **6.1.2** inside a sub-heading like **5.3**.

Think about actually nesting the former inside the latter.

Can you visualise it?